# I get duplicate error when I post same string using NameValuePair

Tags: php, android, json, string, http

I am posting strings to server using Http post, when I post a single string using NameValuePair it works perfectly but when I repeat the same strings I get error of duplicate strings, and does not upload to server. I need any that can accept duplicate strings and its equivalent JSONParser.

```
    List<NameValuePair>params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "me"));
```

This is the error I get when I try to post same string again:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Duplicate of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

The JSON standard doesn't allow to have two entries with the same name. May u want to use an array instead?

**Edit:**
Think what you want to do is something like that:

```
<?php
$json = json_encode(
      1 => array(
          'one',
          'two'
      )
);
?>
```

So its

> {
>   "1": ["one","two"]
>   }

instead of

> {
>   "1":"one",
>   "1":"two"
>   }
>   ?>
>   
>   Or do you mean on the Android site?
>   I can recomment to use [JSON-Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples), thats light & easy.
>   Example:

```
      //import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
      //import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

      JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
      JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
      list.add("bar");
      list.add(new Integer(100));
      list.add(new Double(1000.21));
      list.add(new Boolean(true));
      list.add(null);
      obj.put("foo", list);
      System.out.print(obj);
```

> Result: {"foo": ["foo",100,1000.21,true,null]}

Comment: I will be glad to use anything that can post data to the server of same names so if you have a link to any code i can use to post the data

Comment: i tried but its not working cant post a comment from the same user it says duplicate

Comment: I need some more information to get give precise help: what do you want to do? Send some JSON construct like `{"message":"me","message":"foo"}` ?

Comment: I want to get something like '{"message": "hello man", "username":"mark"  "message": "how are you", "username":"mark" }' i want to get a construct like that which will allow same username

Comment: But thats invalid JSON. you have 3 options: 1) split it into 2 seperate posts 2) `{"message":["hello man", "how are you"], "username":"mark}` 3) `{[{"username":"mark","message":"hello man"},{"username":"mark","message":"how are you"}]}`

Comment: i have been able to reactify the problem, it was my php code which was giving me the insertion problem